# How to change 'deprecated set() and get() in old socket.io code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to node/socket.io and working with an old tutorial to make a chatroom.

Here is socket.js part:

```
exports.initialize = function (server) {
  io = io.listen(server);

  var chatInfra = io.of("/chat_infra")
      .on("connection", function(socket){
        socket.on("set_name", function (data) {
          socket.set('nickname', data.name, function () {
            socket.emit('name_set', data);
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({type:'serverMessage',
              message:'Welcome to the most interesting ' +
              'chat room on earth!'}));
            socket.broadcast.emit('user_entered', data);
          });
        });
      });

  var chatCom = io.of("/chat_com")
      .on("connection", function (socket) {
        socket.on('message', function (message) {
          message = JSON.parse(message);
          if (message.type == "userMessage") {
            socket.get('nickname', function (err, nickname) {
              message.username = nickname;
              socket.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(message));
              message.type = "myMessage";
              socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            });
          }
        });
      });
}
```

But I get

```
TypeError: Object #<Socket> has no method 'set'
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/me/awesome-chat/routes/sockets.js:9:18)
```

I am using `"socket.io": "^1.4.8"` and I know that `set()` is [deprecated](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/) so I tried to chage the set part to use `.use()` as per docs example, but I had no luck in that and got:

```
TypeError: Object #<Socket> has no method 'use'
```

The same goes for the .get() part. 
So I'm really perplexed and appreciate your hints.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you were trying to accomplish when you called `socket.set()` so we can direct you to a better way to do that.

Comment: Well as you can see in the code, it sets username in order to send back a welcome message to the user which includes the user's nickname.

Comment: Sorry, seeing your code does not tell me what you were trying to accomplish with that line of code.  What does "set username" mean?  socket.io sockets don't have a username concept themselves.

Comment: What is your socket.io version?

Comment: @abdulbarik I am using "socket.io": "^1.4.8"

Answer (score 0):

> `Socket#set` and `Socket#get` are not a method of [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/), so it can't be used.
>   Then have to  remove those methods.

you can assign that stuff like this

> socket.nickName = 'Hola' and read it as it is

For getting that value in your code, you can do something like this

```
  .on("connection", function (socket) {
        socket.on('message', function (message) {
          message = JSON.parse(message);
          if (message.type == "userMessage") {
           if(socket && socket.nickname){
              message.username = socket.nickname;
              socket.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(message));
              message.type = "myMessage";
              socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
          };
          }
        });
      });
```

Please see the `Socket.IO API` for details

And here is updated libs of [Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js)

Comment: I knew that. The problem is how?

Comment: you can refer this to do your task may be it  helps you https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js

Comment: I just updated answer with more relative to your stuff, you can set your property and also get it in same way

Comment: Yes this fixes the `.set()` part , but I still have the problem with `get()` method. I tried `message.username = socket.nickname;` But in the browser it turns out to be `undefined`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Can you check your socket object after assigning value, is it exist?

Comment: Not sure how to check it, but it seems to exists because messages appear in the browser but without the corresponding nicknames.

Comment: Can you console your socket object? since if you assigned nickname then it should get in same way. also crosscheck your variable name

Comment: If it not exist in socket object then it can't get

Comment: My problem is how to rewrite this `socket.get('nickname', function (err, nickname) {` without `.get()` method.

Comment: Did you console your socket object and got nickname value?

Comment: Above code must be work if you get nickname value in socket object

Comment: Well, in the console `socket` and `socket.nickname` both cause this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: socket is not defined`

Comment: Please check your socket object scope, I think you are printing it out of scope. Since its reference error throwing ;)